# Get n items from list of list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List containing another List of Users/Players. These users are grouped and sorted by their golf handicaps with particular ranges. For instance the inner list containing indexes of

[0]=>Count 2 (Players)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3uro.png)=>Count 3 (Players)

[2]=>Count 1 (Players)

In order to make flights in a tournament, these player/user are grouped with limit of 3 or 4 players in a each flight. How do I fill each flight according to the limit specified. Zero index contains 2 players, so I have to take rest 2 players from the next index and so on to compensate the players.

For all this above I'm trying to use LINQ query to execute such functionality, but I'm unable to work out this. Below is what I have tried.

```
List<List<Models.User>> PlayerSortedList = new List<List<Models.User>>(); //contains all the grouped players 

foreach (var item in PlayerSortedList)
{
var extraPlayers = new List<Models.User>();

if (item.Count != Convert.ToInt16(vm.flight.PlayerLimit))
{
//Take extra players from next list and remove players from the next list
 int limit = Convert.ToInt16(vm.flight.PlayerLimit) - item.Count;
 var players = PlayerSortedList.Skip(i); // this has not skipped the first index


 extraPlayers = (from player in players
 from p in player
 where player.Count > 0
 orderby (p.UserHandicap).Take(limit)
 select p).ToList(); // generating error as must be icomparable but i dont 
 have to compare anything, but take out players from the next items in the list
}
```

By taking extra player from the next items in the list, i do have to add them in the previous list as well as remove those players from the list from which i have taken out.

[image]

Comment: So the corresponding output for the input you showed would be "4 players in index 0, 2 players in index 1"?

Comment: 4 players in each index, keep iterating thought all the players in the list until the limit reaches to 4.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by "keep iterating thought all the players in the list until the limit reaches to 4". You can't have 4 players in each index because you only have 6 players, which is not divisible by 4. Can you just show the final list you want from this?

Comment: Let me add a screen shot.

Comment: In case of last flight not having 4 players, i would have to equal the number of players in the second last and last flights.

Comment: I don't see how the desired result relates to the input. Can you explain? Note that I don't play golf, maybe that's the reason why I don't get this...

Comment: What about SelectMany, and instead of having lists of lists of players, only have lists of players. Then modules 4 to get the number of players that do not end up in a flight of 4 players. Then loop over the players with an increment of 4, where max is: (number of players)-(outcome of modules). The remaining players you will have to entertain someway else :D Or you could modules with 3 and 4, see what yields the least players that will not fit in a flight of 3 or 4.

Comment: The desired result is not in the screen shot. It is just to let you have the idea of players inside the flights. At this time I'm not having equal number of players in each flight.

Comment: morelinq's [Batch method](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#batch).

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfListOfPlayers = new List<List<Player>>();
        //Flatten the list, so not having to deal with lists of lists
        var allPlayers = listOfListOfPlayers.SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
        //Count the players that can not take part of a flight
        var playersNotFittingInFlight = allPlayers.Count % 4;
        //The number of players that will be spread in flights
        var maxPlayersInFlights = allPlayers.Count - playersNotFittingInFlight;
        //The number of flights you will end up having
        var maxFlights = maxPlayersInFlights / 4;
        var flights = new List<Flight>(maxFlights);
        //Create the flights with the players
        for (var i=0;i<maxPlayersInFlights; i=i+4)
        {
            var flight = new Flight();
            //Take 4 players everytime.
            var players = allPlayers.Skip(i).Take(4);
            flight.Players.AddRange(players);
            flights.Add(flight);
        }
    }

    public class Flight
    {
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; } = new List<Player>();
    }

    public class Player
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why Skip(i*4) and not just Skip(i)?

Comment: @SalarMuhammad Good catch. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this by using a single linq query.

```
var limit = 4;
var results = playerSortedList
    // Combine all the users in the lists into a single list
    .SelectMany(l => l) 
    // .SelectMany(l => l.OrderBy(x=>x.Handicap)) // use this in case it is needed to reorder the users within each sub list.

    // Use index of the users within the list to create bucket numbers.
    .Select((user, idx) => new { User = user, Bucket = (idx / limit) })

    // Group the users using the bucket numbers.
    .GroupBy(x => x.Bucket)

    // Make the whole thing a List<List<User>> again.
    .Select(x=>x.Select(bucket => bucket.User).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Kind regards,
D.